# Can't correctly obtain OAuth to append to google sheet via Javascript http request

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I can't for the life of me append to my google sheet via http request. More specifically I can't seem to get the Oauth formatting right. I don't want/need a uri or prompt for permission as its just me managing my own spreadsheet. First, I was trying with just my api key, but then found out that if you're editing data you need to obtain an access token. That's when I started trying to obtain the token through oauth2 following the TERRIBLE google api documentation. That's where I hit a wall and have just about given up. It's such a simple concept, I just want to add data to my spreadsheet on drive from an online script (housed on scriptr.io), but Google yet again makes things so unneccessarily complicated and don't help matters with their convoluted, misleading, and scattered documentation. Can someone please help me in accomplishing this? Here's where I'm at or what progress I've made thus far.

I've figured out how to correctly format the call to add a row of data to the spreadsheet.

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/-/values/Raw%20Data!A1:D1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
//Header
Authorization: Bearer {oauth_token}
//Payload
{"range": "Raw Data!A1:D1","majorDimension": "ROWS","values": [["Test", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"]]}
```

I know the above works because I've successfully added the data using the OAuth 2.0 Playground. However, when trying it outside of the playground (on a rest client) I keep getting errors trying to obtain the token.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
client_id=------&
client_secret=-----&
refresh_token=-----&
grant_type=refresh_token&
access_type=offline
```

I use the client id & client secret from my api console and I use the refresh token I got by authorizing the spreadsheet api in the oauth playground, but the above POST request leads to the following error

```
Error 400
{
"error": "unsupported_grant_type",
"error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to correctly do this?

Comment: Instead of a refresh token, can you try passing the "Authorization code" from Google Oauth Playground to see if it works?

Comment: Doesn't the Authorization code expire though?

Comment: Also, could you provide an example POST please? Just so I know how to correctly format it (using the correct params)

Comment: You are trying to get new access token with your refresh token apparently. Try to remove the "&access_type=offline" parameter, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I've tried it without the `access_type`, but it's the same result